# put files inside of a custom made folder request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I got this code that loops inside of a FireStore database, gets the URLs stored in there, and downloads it to my phone;

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(placee).child("תמונות").child(year).child(eventcase.getCaseInfo()).child(getmonth1).child(nameGet1+ "-" + idGet1);
mDatabaseReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        mStoredPictures = new ArrayList<>();

        if (snapshot.exists()) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                StoredPicture storedPicture = postSnapShot.getValue(StoredPicture.class);
                mStoredPictures.add(storedPicture);
                storedPicture.getmImageUrl();

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(storedPicture.getmImageUrl()));
                String title= URLUtil.guessFileName(storedPicture.getmImageUrl(),null,null);
                request.setTitle(nameGet1+ "-" + idGet1);
                request.setDescription("----");
                String cookie=CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(storedPicture.getmImageUrl());
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookie);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,title);
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(SearchCase.this, "מוריד תמונות/סרטונים...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }
```

the code works but it puts all the files inside of the download folder. I want it to be put it inside a custom-made folder.

I tried to write;

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/folder/innerFolder",title);
```

but it just gives me the "Not one of the standard directories:" ERROR.

Comment: Why would you need to download the file?

Comment: the mannager told me to have this fanction

Comment: `want it to be put it inside a custom-made folder.` But that is no public dir. You have to indicate a public dir there as the function name clearly indicates. But you can make your custom folder inside a public dir. Thats all.

Comment: And how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use [DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method that doesn't have a context argument but [setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method that does.

Comment: why should i not use it?

Comment: Because the other overloaded method can be called with a context. Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` can pretty well be used. You did not make clear why it should not be used. Or why an alternative should come from context.

Comment: Have you tried to use the other method? Does it work?